# SunRPC enable one way messaging (streaming / batching?)

Tags: c, linux, rpc, sunrpc

We have some services utilizing SunRPC on Linux (RHEL 4/5) that we'd like to speed up.

Our RPC call require no return value, though by the nature of RPC, an ack is always sent anyway. This introduces latency that's recently become a problem - when run over a reliable transport (TCP), we'd hope to avoid the latency introduced by the RPC reply.

Docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1671/modif-14.html#scrolltoc) indicates Solaris has the "oneway" keyword enabling just that, though Linux/glibc does not seem to support this.

Is there any way we can enable "streaming" or one-way messaging with SunRPC on Linux ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two changes that must be made to the standard `clnt_call()` invocation in order to obtain an asynchronous (or "batched") RPC call: the argument that's the pointer to the XDR function for the reply data-structure must be `NULL` and the timeout argument must be zero, i.e.,

```
static struct timeval ZERO_TIMEOUT = { 0, 0 };
static char clnt_res;
memset((char*)&clnt_res, 0, sizeof(clnt_res);
if (clnt_call(clnt, messageType, (xdrproc_t)xdr_messageType_t, (caddr_t)argp,
            (xdrproc_t)NULL, (caddr_t)&clnt_res, ZERO_TIMEOUT) != RPC_SUCCESS) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your RPC library does not support the "oneway" communication, then you can always use the [Thread Pool Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) to emulate the "fire and forget" kind of invocation in your program. Instead of sending the remote call directly (and thus blocking until you receive an answer) you enqueue a [command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) that does the remote call in a different thread and allows you main program to continue with it's execution.